# Динамическое изменение содержимого страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

у меня есть 3 блока "div", которые по клику на тэг "a" должны менять class на "active" (отображаться), а остальные - убирать его. 
Я нашел такой скрипт и он отлично работает по клику на изображение, но не на мой тэг "a". Почему? 
Изначальный вид скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.contains img').click(function () {
            $(".contains img").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            $(".object").removeClass("active");
            $("#" + $(this).attr("alt")).addClass("active");
        });
    </script>
```

Мой пример: (img заменил на a и вместо атрибута "alt" дал "name")

```
<a class="active" name="test-1">Кальянная 1</a>
<a name="test-2">Кальянная 2</a>
```

Тэги "div" для содержимого:

```
<div class="containter">
    <div class="hookah active" id="test-1">
    //содержимое
    </div>

    <div class="hookah" id="test-2">
    //содержимое 2
    </div>
</div>
```

После преобразований, я переписал скрипт таким образом:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.container a').click(function () {
        $(".container a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        $(".hookah").removeClass("active");
        $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).addClass("active");
    });
   </script>
```

Но он почему-то не работает. Заранее спасибо.

плюсом, если будет полезно, маленькая вырезка из css:

```
.hookah {
//стили
display: none;
}
  .hookah.active{
    display: block;
    }
```

Дополнительно прикладываю верстку для работающего скрипта (с картинками):

```
<div class="landing-page">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="contains">
                    <img src="" alt="test-1" class="active" />
                    <img src="" alt="test-2" />
                    <img src="" alt="test-3" />
                    <div class="hookah active" id="test-1">
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hookah" id="test-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hookah" id="test-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href=""</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: $(".container a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
вы же здесь добавляете и удаляете класс актив у одного и того же елемента

Comment: @Arendach, насколько я понимаю, removeClass("active"); убирается у первого тэга "a" и, допустим, при клике на второй "a" он добавится там.
А так да, вы правы, если кликнуть на уже имеющийся класс active (например в 1 случае), то он удалит active и его добавит. 
В общем, не вижу противоречий

Comment: в данном контексте `$('.container a') == $(this)`

Comment: $(".object").removeClass("active"); вы здесь поменяли а в верстке `hookah`? или там вы тоже поменяли?

Comment: Наверное мы друг друга понимаем не до конца. Если бы добавлялся и удалялся класс active у одного и того же элемента, переключения бы не было, так? Но оно есть (правда для изображений на другой странице) и this == "кликнутому a" (если так можно сказать) @Arendach

Comment: да возможно у нас недопонимание, я не вижу всей картины целиком да и после 8 часов работы...

Comment: @Arendach добавил в описание верстку без текста и пр. мусора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл подключить jQuery, очень досадно! Поэтому ничего не работало и скрипт изначально был верно подстроен.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем html ссылки не находятся внутри элемента с классом `container`.

```js
$('.switches a').click(function() {
  $(".switches a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".containter .hookah").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switches">
  <a class="active" name="test-1">Кальянная 1</a>
  <a name="test-2">Кальянная 2</a>
</div>

<br/>
<br/> Тэги "div" для содержимого:
<br/>

<div class="containter">
  <div class="hookah active" id="test-1">
    //содержимое
  </div>

  <div class="hookah" id="test-2">
    //содержимое 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает. Однако, есть один минус в скрипте:

$(".containter .hookah").removeClass("active");

в данной строке надо убрать .container, потому что он из-за этого не удаляет класс (на странице по клику остается 2 "содержимого", но они не меняют друг друга)

Comment: @Revasha Не возражаю :).